# Using ExecutorService to process jobs in parallel

Tags: java, web-crawler, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am writing a java program that needs to process a lot of URLs.
Each URLs will run the following jobs IN ORDER: download, analyze, compress

Instead of having one single thread to do all the jobs at once per URL, I want each job to have a fixed amount of threads, so that all the jobs will have threads running concurrently at any given time.

For example, the download job will have multiple threads to fetch and download URLs, as soon as one of the URL is downloaded, it will pass it on to a thread in analyze job and as soon as it completes, it will then pass on to a thread in compress job, etc.

I am thinking of using the CompletionService in java, since it returns a result as soon as its finished, but I am not sure how it works, so far my code looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
CompletionService<DownloadedItem> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<DownloadedItem>(executor);

//while list has URL do {
   executor.submit(new DownloadJob(list.getNextURL());//submit to queue for download
//}

//while there is URL left do {
   Future<DownloadedItem> downloadedItem = executor.take();//take the result as soon as it finish
   //what to do here??
//}
```

My question is how do I move the downloaded item to the analyze job and do the work there without waiting for all the download jobs to complete? I am thinking of creating a CompletionService for each job, is that a viable method? If not, is there a better alternative way to solve this problem? Please provide examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you mention `IN ORDER` any attempt to use separate threads for those in order tasks will only complicate the design of your system.

In my opinion, your best shot is to have separate threads handle individual URLs at once. To do the 3 steps you can introduce another abstraction (like use 3 callables) but you still want to execute them sequentially in one thread. And no need for completion service.

Comment: The thing is I want optimize the connection for the download Job, since I want to have fixed number of connection running, if I make a single thread to do all 3 jobs I cannot guarantee at least some threads will be connecting at a given time.

Comment: Ok. I agree that if some step may run significantly slower that others there are may be a possibility of scaling whole thing better by fine tuning 3 separate thread pools. But I'd consider it a premature optimization before it's determined that you underutilize cpu.

Comment: Say, I would be running it on a distributed system instead of a single system, would it be better to separate the jobs into different threadpools like the one I have above?

Comment: It makes more sense with multiple hosts. Your goal would be to have equally high CPU utilization on all hosts. So you would put more hosts in the pool or more threads in thread pool on single VM. You would use message queue between hosts. That's similar to pipeline that someone described. Yet you should have darn good reason to add all this complexity.  I'd implement it in simple way first then evaluate and based on results consider something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. First submit your tasks to `CompletionService` instead:

```
completionService.submit(new DownloadJob(list.getNextURL());
```

Now grab `Future` and wait for it:

```
DownloadedItem> downloadedItem = executor.take().get();
```

Call to `get()` might block. Repeat the line above as many times as many items you submitted.

---

If you need much, much greater throughput (in your case at most three URLs will be downloaded at a time), consider [`async-http-client`](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client#readme) which will allow you to download from literally thousands of URLs simultaneously. It uses NIO and is event driven, no threading is involved.

Comment: Yes, but how would I pass the downloaded item to the analyze job without waiting for all the download jobs to complete?

Comment: You wrap the while loop that handles moving the results over in a `Thread` of its own. This could be a simple anonymous inner-class defining that `Thread`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called a [Pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29). Basically the output of the download task is the input of the analyze task. The output of analyze is the input of compress. There seem to be two options to accomplish this:

1) Let the download task know about the pipeline for ouput so that it can submit the results itself.

```
class DownloadTask implement Runnable {
    Executor analyzePipeline;
    public void run() {
        //Do download stuff
        analyzePipeline.submit(new AnalyzeTask(downloaded content));
    }
}
```

2) Allow another thread to move the results from the download tasks into the pipeline for the analyze task.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
ExecutorService analyzeExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
CompletionService<DownloadedItem> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<DownloadedItem>(executor);

while list has URL do {
   executor.submit(new DownloadJob(list.getNextURL());//submit to queue for download
}

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while there is URL left do {
            Future<DownloadedItem> downloadedItem = executor.take();//take the result as soon as it finish
            analyzeExecutor.submit(new AnalyzeJob(downloadedItem.get());
        }
    }
};    
//...and so on
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seems to understand why you have to use a thread in 2) to move downloaded task to analyze task(or pipeline), if at 1) you already specify that the downloaded task would submit the result to the pipeline. Could you clarify this part for me? thanks.

Comment: Waiting for the jobs to complete (`CompletionService.take`) is a blocking operation. If you want a pipeline model, you need to facilitate the movement of data between phases of the pipeline. If you insist on using a `CompletionService` and don't want added latency, then you need yet another Thread (which will be mostly idle) to do that facilitation. For what it's worth, I think you've accepted the right answer. With the proper number of threads, the system will balance itself out since each task involves heavy IO and heavy CPU phases.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tim, if so I have decided to use a pipeline model, what would be a better way to approach this instead of using completionservice? I know this question is a bit vague, but I want to know how my program will fit against this model.

Comment: Assume that I am using a distributed system.